# Why is the Show Smart Tag button disabled in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am following the tutorial from

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t32yf0a9(v=vs.100).aspx

and am getting stuck at the section "To link to the restricted pages". Following the steps there doesn't get me anywehre as my Show Smart tag button is disabled.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: where did you right click? Following the tutorial, you should click on the menu control (`asp:Menu`), you are clicking on the `asp:ContentPlaceHolder`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your menu item will be inside an unordered list , use asp Menu tag instead.

Try like this

```
 <asp:Menu ID="navMenu" runat="server" >
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" NavigateUrl="Default.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="About" NavigateUrl="About.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact Us" NavigateUrl="Contact.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
```

instead of this

```
 <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

This will work.